# 1С Битрикс вывод элемента количества товара в корзине при определённом условии

Tags: php, битрикс, mustache

В общем есть кастомное поле "PROPERTY_VID" в товаре. Принимает два значения "новое" или "бу".
Необходимо, чтобы выбор количества в товара в корзине, был доступен только для товаров, у которых кастомное поле равно "новое".
Я так понимаю, отредактировать необходимо шаблон (bitrix\components\bitrix\sale.basket.basket\templates.default\js-templates\basket-item.php), сделать сравнение по значению параметра, вот только как до него достучаться?
Дошёл вот до чего:

```php
<?php
if (!empty($arParams['PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER'])) {
    foreach ($arParams['PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER'] as $blockName) {
        switch (trim((string)$blockName)) {
            case 'columns':
            ?>
            {{#COLUMN_LIST}}
                {{#IS_TEXT}}
                    {{NAME}}
                    {{VALUE}}
                {{/IS_TEXT}}
            {{/COLUMN_LIST}}
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

До нужных данных достучался. Но за вывод отвечает шаблонизатор mustache.js, который в свою очередь не имеет логики, т.е. вот так например:

```
{{#VALUE == "бу"}}
```

он не умеет.
Пробовал сравнить через php вот так:

```php
<?php
if (!empty($arParams['PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER'])) {
    foreach ($arParams['PRODUCT_BLOCKS_ORDER'] as $blockName) {
        switch (trim((string)$blockName)) {
            case 'columns':
            ?>
            {{#COLUMN_LIST}}
                {{#IS_TEXT}}
                <?php
                    $text_name = "{{NAME}}";
                    $text_value = "{{VALUE}}";
                    if ($text_value == "бу"):
                        echo $text_value;
                    endif;
                ?>
                {{/IS_TEXT}}
            {{/COLUMN_LIST}}
            <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

И тут вообще ничего не понимаю, сравнивать он их не хочет, я уже и типы данных сверял, и приводил к строке перед сравнением и посимвольное сравнение строк делал, не работает.
Странно то, если перед сравнением вывести:

```php
echo $text_value;
```

содержимое переменной выводит.

Уже не знаю куда копать.
Может я изначально не в те дебри полез?!

Answer (score 2):

Выводишь архив в php, вот так:

```
print_r($arResult['BASKET_ITEM_RENDER_DATA']);
```

Смотришь в каком поле у тебя твоё свойство PROPERTY_VID, например, оно у тебя во 2 поле, то-есть в php ты выводишь NAME вот так:

```
echo $arResult[...]['COLUMN_LIST'][2]['NAME'];
```

Значит в корзине битрикса ты обращаешься к нему так:

```
{{COLUMN_LIST.2.NAME}}
```

Ну а значение, соответственно, получаешь так:

```
{{COLUMN_LIST.2.VALUE}}
```